# Integrating JW player with ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jwplayer

The jwplayer website suggests that you embed jwplayer inside javascript this way:

```
jwplayer("videoDIV").setup({
                  file: "vid.flv",
                  height: 300,
                  width: 400,
                  //Etc...
```

However, when I try that in ASP.NET I get

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setup' of null`

I should just be able to call `jwplayer` like a variable, and it should be accessible as long as I have the `<script src...` stuff, right?

---

The error appears on the `jwplayer("videoDIV").setup({` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why this happens.

When you call `jwplayer(string)setup()`, the string there **needs** to be a div by that name in your html.